# Setting up my first Varnish Cache server

Tags: varnish

I am attempting to set up my first Varnish Cache server and I have a couple questions for any person(s) experienced.

1.) I am running Varnish as a stand alone server. Do I need Apache also installed on the same server. Ultimately the actual site that will be behind Varnish is not on this server.

2.) Do I point the domain to Varnish and then set the config to point to the ip address of the server that is hosting the site? If so, how do you point it to the right site?

3.) If Varnish is standalone and I have an Apache content server, can they both be port 80 and just change the ip address in the default.vcl

backend default {
  .host = "198.221.134.235";
  .port = "80";
}

Sorry for the basic questions. I have been on Google all weekend and I found plenty of information on how to install and config Varnish but it seems like the site you want to Cache is on the same server since all of them are changing the port Apache listens to and that seems like it would mean the site is living on the same server.

And if you have any good sites with information, please feel free to share them! Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, Varnish and Apache (or any other HTTP/webserver) can run on a separate server.
2. Indeed, point the domain to the IP of Varnish and setup a backend as described in the documentation: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/backend_servers.html. The IP
   of your webserver will be the IP of the backend.
3. Correct, as long as Apache and Varnish are on separate servers they both can listen on port 80

If I am not mistaken you will have the following setup:

`DNS example.com => 1.1.1.1
IP 1.1.1.1:80: Varnish (backend: 1.1.1.2:80)
IP 1.1.1.2:80: Apache`

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. When defining a default backend, you would point that to the Apache server's IP address that is serving the web site, correct? And if so, how can you define what site it goes to? Does Varnish pass the URL to the apache server so the conf file can route it correctly? Lets say I want to have therecord.org use varnish. I point the DNS record of the domain to the varnish server (198.221.134.235) then want the varnish server to point to the Apache server (198.221.134.236) that is hosting the Drupal site. How does Apache know which site to serve?

Comment: The default backend points to Apache indeed. Apache will act exactly the same as if you point the domain directly to Apache. Depending on the configuration (for example the hostname) Apache will serve the correct vhost. Varnish acts as a man in the middle and will (by default) do nothing more then forwarding the request to the backend and do the caching when possible.

Comment: Cool. Just to reset. I point the DNS to the Varnish server IPAdress. I use the default.vcl and add 
backend default {
  .host = "198.221.134.236";
  .port = "80";
to point to the Apache server. Then on apache I can have a vhost file that says serverName = therecord.org and points to /var/www/html/therecord.com and if I point my browser to therecord.com it will work?
}

Comment: I meant point to the browser to the correct domain therecord.org

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. Seems my config is correct...just having an issue with port 80 opening on the cache server now lol. Thank you very much!